# Identifying a MOSFET marked D1GNA and 2R1H01

Tags: mosfet, identification

The MOSFET is on a laptop motherboard close to the power jack. The part reads:
`D1 GNA` and `2R1H01`
It's faulty so I'm looking to replace it.

I added some pictures of the area + the MOSFET. The laptop is an HP Elitebook 850 G1 (I haven't had any luck finding schematics but maybe someone else has more luck). And I found this code on the motherboard: 6050A2560201-MB-A03.

[image: photo of device]

[image: photo of PCB]

Comment: Are you even sure it's a MOSFET and not some other device in a similar package?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is just the way the picture was taken, but the 3-pin device _north east_ of ``SW152`` gives the appearance that the device may have overheated. On closer inspection, are there any devices with sign of damage such as a cracked package?

Comment: Hello, the component appears completely normal under the microscope. It appears my camera didn't do it justice. I have also looked at other components in the region and none of them have any signs of damage.

Comment: From the marking style, the manufacturer is likely [Niko-Sem](https://www.niko-sem.com/) or [Unikc](https://www.unikc.com.cn/en), I can't find a part with a "D1" product code though.

Comment: Really odd that there is nothing on the internet about this MOSFET. Do you think there might be another MOSFET I can get away with using as a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in the datasheet of the "HP EliteBook 840 G1" and looking for Q6010 I now believe it to be the `AON7403` MOSFET. I don't know enough about MOSFET's to confirm this however. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, AO doesn't seem to put part marking information in their datasheets. What leads you to think it's an AON740?

Comment: On the datasheet of a similar laptop motherboard, right under Q6010 it says ```ALPHA_AON7403L_DFN_8P```. This brought me to the AON7403, the MOSFET's appear to look identical. I'm not certain but it's the best I can find.

Comment: Without knowing what it's doing, I can't say for certain, but the AON7403 seems like a reasonable enough MOSFET. It can be driven at 10 V or at 5 V and has reasonably low on-resistance at either drive condition. The package is a common one, so "looks identical" isn't really enough of a clue (there are thousands of MOSFETs that look identical to this one if you ignore the markings), but the characteristics look pretty reasonable for a power FET on a computer motherboard. The only problem is that it's obsolete, so you might need to replace it with a different part. AO recommends their AONR21321.

Comment: @Hearth The search https://aosmd.com/resource-library?refinementList%5Bcategory%5D%5B0%5D=markings&page=1&configure%5Bfilters%5D=search_api_language%3Aen&configure%5BhitsPerPage%5D=50&query=AON7403 is filtered on the aosmd.com site for markings for AON7403. It finds https://aosmd.com/sites/default/files/res/markings/AON7403.pdf. The marking in that document doesn't match that from the picture in the question, but could be compatible in a ``DFN3X3`` package.

Comment: @ChesterGillon The main problem, I suppose, is figuring out if it's supposed to be a P-channel or N-channel FET in that position. After you know that, probably most reasonably-spec'd FETs would work. It doesn't look like this is part of a switching converter (no nearby inductor) so you wouldn't need to be as careful about capacitances.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a [Unikc PZ2003EEA](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1094144/UNIKC/PZ2003EEA/1) P-channel MOSFET. The datasheet doesn't specify the markings, but I found a listing on shopee with a (low quality) picture that shows a "D1" product code.

[image]

(Source: [shopee.co.id](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qZuKQaSnUf4J:https://shopee.co.id/search%3Fkeyword%3Dd1hw&hl=de&gl=de))

Here is a better picture of another Unikc MOSFET (PE534BA) in the same package that shows the marking style of this manufacturer as reference.

[image]

(Source: [aliexpress.com](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/4000225180822.html?src=google&aff_fcid=91ff05534ce9416aa8d4806902a82bcd-1703155619285-07263-UneMJZVf&aff_fsk=UneMJZVf&aff_platform=aaf&sk=UneMJZVf&aff_trace_key=91ff05534ce9416aa8d4806902a82bcd-1703155619285-07263-UneMJZVf&terminal_id=bf341379b04f4d21b63bbccb56305de5&afSmartRedirect=y))

Note: The MOSFET is also available from [Niko-sem](https://www.niko-sem.com/).